# Pearson’s Correlation Coefficient >=-1 & <=1

Tags: correlation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Pearson’s Correlation Coefficient is defined as follows:

$$
=\frac{\left(,\right)}{_x_y}=\frac{\left[\left(−_x\right)\left(−_y\right)\right]}{\sqrt{E\left(\left[\left(−_x\right)^2\right]\right)}\sqrt{E\left(\left[\left(y−_y\right)^2\right]\right)}}
$$

how can I show that −1≤≤1  using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality ?
Can anyone maybe give a link to a good explanation or a book with a detailed proof which uses Cauchy–Schwarz inequality ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/564843/551592